# How to Do Java EE Container Security With MongoDB on Tomcat

Tags: java, mongodb, security, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have used file realm and JDBC realm before to host the username and password combinations. I have not yet used MongoDB to perform the same function. I have read the Tomcat docs and searched around but have not seen any tutorials.

Is there a realm someone knows of or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own realm and manually connect to Mongo.

This article here describes the process and provides sample code:

http://www.tomitribe.com/blog/2013/10/creating-a-mongodb-security-realm-for-tomcat/